# Wifi ad-hoc network with smartphones

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

Suppose I want to setup a wifi ad-hoc network with multiple phones (three for this example).
I have questions for this setup:

- Do you need to connect as slave and master (like you do with Bluetooth)?
- Can you be connected to multiple masters?

Basically, I need phone A to connect with B and C; B with A and C.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there are no master or slaves. Wi-Fi ad hoc networks (technically called IEEE 802.11 IBSS networks) are **completely** peer-to-peer. All members of the network share the duties equally. The originator of the network is not special in any way. At least not at the 802.11 layer; you could always have one device that provides more services at higher layers, but at the 802.11 layer (layer 2; the data link layer in the OSI model) all IBSS peers are completely equal peers.